# python, turtles, pi and monte carlo

Tags: python, montecarlo, pi, approximation

I'm trying to approximate pi using a monte carlo with turtles in python. The code is running well but I've got a problem, my "approximations" are all terribly wrong. I' always get values smaller than 1 so??? My code is here below

```
import turtle
import math
import random

fred = turtle.Turtle()
fred.speed(0)
fred.up()

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.setworldcoordinates(-1,-1,1,1)

numdarts = int(input("How many darts will you throw"))
for i in range(numdarts):
x = random.random()
y = random.random()
numIncircle = 0

if i == 0 or i == 1:
    fred.up()
    fred.goto(x, y)


    if fred.distance(0, 0) <= 1:
        numIncircle += 1
        fred.color("Indianred")
        fred.stamp()
        fred.up()
    else:
        numIncircle += 0
        fred.color("cyan")
        fred.stamp()
        fred.up()


else:
    fred.goto(x, y)

    if fred.distance(0, 0) <= 1:
        numIncircle += 1
        fred.color("Indianred")
        fred.stamp()
        fred.up()
    else:
        numIncircle += 0
        fred.color("cyan")
        fred.stamp()
        fred.up()

piapproximation = float(float(numIncircle) / float(numdarts)) * 4

print piapproximation

wn.exitonclick()
```

Comment: [`random.random()`](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html) returns a value between 0 and +1. You've set `turtle.Screen().setworldcoordinates(-1,-1,1,1)`. Shouldn't you have `x` and `y` = `random.random() * 2 - 1`?

Comment: well now I get a whole circle instead of only a quarter of it, which looks nice but unfortunately changes nothing about the outcome of the approximation :(

Comment: Yeah, I knew it wouldn't help with your question so posted it as a comment. What values **do** you get when the number of darts is large? Something close to [0.78539816339](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=pi+%2F+4&x=0&y=0)?

Comment: Well I tried it twice with 2000 darts and I get 0.0 twice, which is weird because numIncircle isn't zero right?

Comment: I know! :D Posting answer now.

Comment: Having 'turtles' in the title made me want to answer. Calling it `fred` sealed the deal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting `numIncircle = 0` **inside** your `for` loop, effectively losing count each time.

Occasionally it'll count the last one, so the approximation will be 1 / number of darts * 4. This will happen with frequency [pi / 4 ≈ 0.78539816339](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=pi+%2F+4&x=0&y=0).

Here is my suggestion:

```
import turtle
import math
import random

fred = turtle.Turtle()
fred.speed(0)
fred.up()

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.setworldcoordinates(-1,-1,1,1)

numdarts = int(input("How many darts will you throw"))

// this MUST come before the for loop
numIncircle = 0

for i in range(numdarts):
x = random.random() * 2 - 1
y = random.random() * 2 - 1

if i == 0 or i == 1:
    fred.up()
    fred.goto(x, y)

    if fred.distance(0, 0) <= 1:
        numIncircle += 1
        fred.color("Indianred")
        fred.stamp()
        fred.up()
    else:
        numIncircle += 0
        fred.color("cyan")
        fred.stamp()
        fred.up()
else:
    fred.goto(x, y)

    if fred.distance(0, 0) <= 1:
        numIncircle += 1
        fred.color("Indianred")
        fred.stamp()
        fred.up()
    else:
        numIncircle += 0
        fred.color("cyan")
        fred.stamp()
        fred.up()

piapproximation = float(float(numIncircle) / float(numdarts)) * 4

print piapproximation

wn.exitonclick()
```